# Display Wordpress posts

Tags: 7

I currently have both a Drupal and a WordPress site. Is there a module that can display the latest posts from my WordPress site, or will I need to write my own?

Answer (score 6):

The Aggregator module that ships with Drupal core can pull in posts from the WordPress site's RSS feed. For more functionality and overall flexibility, you could use the [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

Assuming Wordpress makes your posts available using RSS, the module built-in within Drupal's core may be an answer: [Aggregator Drupal module](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/aggregator)